# Bash | curl | curls 2 URL's then stops

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am trying to write a simple bash script that will use a list from a text document and curl each URL that is on the list in order to see what the contents of each URL is. It allows me to cURL 2 sites and creates the text documents for the rest however it only downloads the first 2. I have already manage to write the script that pulls there IP's and places them in a seperate file using the grep command.  At first i tried

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in `cat host.txt`; do
curl -s $var >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html
done
```

I have tried with and without the silent switch. I then tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash  
for var in `head -2 host.txt`; do  
curl $var >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html  
wait  
done  
for var in `head -4 host.txt | tail -2`; do  
curl $var >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html  
done
```

This would try and do them all at the same time again stopping after 2

```
#!/bin/bash  
for var in `head -2 host.txt`; do  
curl $var >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html   
done 
wait 
for var in `head -4 host.txt | tail -2`; do  
curl $var >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html  
done
```

This would do the same, I am new to bash scripting and only know some of the basics, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do the urls have & characters in them? Or spaces?

Comment: No they only contain, letters, numbers and -

Comment: `| tail -2` tells it to only use `2` lines from the output; That would be a very big reason as to why it stops after only 2. The same goes for `head -2`.

Comment: True however i have added      head -4  therefore it does the last 2 lines from 4

Comment: You're stating that the problem is that it stops after downloading `2`. It doesn't matter what you have *before* the pipe (`head -4`), the `tail -2` is what's used in the `for` loop, therefore `curl` only downloads 2 urls. If you remove it, it will download `4`; If you just do `cat host.txt`, it will download all of them.

Comment: Thats what i tried to begin with hence the reason i changed it. when running cat host.txt it would only curl 2, it would try and curl more however it would just freeze and do nothing,, for the second script it tried to download the right URL's so it does get the ones i need, no duplications, however does the same as previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the simple: verify that you are in fact iterating over the entire list:

```
# This is the recommended way to iterate over the file. See
# http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
while read -r var; do
    echo "$var"
done < hosts.txt
```

Then add in the call to `curl`, checking its exit status

```
while read -r var; do
    echo "$var"
    curl "$var" >> /tmp/ping/html/$var.html || echo "curl failed: $?"
done < hosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You pipe into $var, which could result in a wrong filename, because of the two slashes in the URL. Additionally i would quote the URL. For Example it works with the basename of the URL.

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in `cat host.txt`; do
  name=$(basename $var)
  curl -v -s "$var" -o "/tmp/ping/html/$name.html"
done
```

You may also want to skip blank lines and Comments (#)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="host.txt"
curl="curl"

while read -r line
  do
    [[ $line = \#* ]] || [[  -z "${line}" ]]  && continue
    filename=$(basename $line)
    $curl -s "$line" >> "/tmp/ping/html/$filename.html"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: thank you,, however this does not rectify the issue i am having with the curl command freezing after 2, if his helps it will bring up the progress bar however will only download the first 2 and sometimes a random one in the list will be partially downloaded. the script doesnt finish even with only 3 urls

Comment: Try my example verbose.  

`curl -v -s "$var" >> "./$name.html"` 

Your head and tail calls limits the amount of downloads.